# Table name passing as parameter in u-sql

Tags: azure, u-sql

I am trying to create u-SQL tables through azure data factory in which, i am trying to pass table name and database names as activity parameter. How to do this?

the create table script is as under:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS @db_name;
USE DATABASE @db_name;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS @db_name.@ref.@table_name
(
    [MS-DR] string,
    [Final_Post] string,
    [Final_Special] string,     
    [Weights] float?,
    [Geometric_Mean] float?,
    [Arithmetic_Mean] float?,
    [Year] string,
    [Version] string,
    [Inserted_Ts] DateTime,
        INDEX CWIDX
        CLUSTERED([MS-DR] ASC)
        DISTRIBUTED BY HASH([MS-DR])
);
```

And I am trying to pass the parameters using the parameter section in data factory which is as under:

```
"parameters": {
          "db_name": "db_ob_main",
          "table_name": "cost_wght_tbl"
      }
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried giving the comments using "DECLARE EXTERNAL" statements too.., but no use..

Answer (score 1):

Database/schema are not parameterizable in U-SQL.

If you want to pass in other parameters via ADF, you should use DECLARE EXTERNAL statements in the script and also declare the parameters in ADF. ADF passes in parameters by writing in a DECLARE statement at the top of the script. If you declare the variables as DECLARE EXTERNAL, your script can run independently of ADF but won't cause errors when ADF writes in an earlier DECLARE statement ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/declare-variables-u-sql)).

Comment: I know hiw to declare variables in U-SQL and how to pass parameters like files through ADF but my problem is with database and table name only

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible.  Database, schema, and table names cannot be passed as parameters in U-SQL.

Comment: Please note that parameterizing database object names is not supported by any common SQL dialect (e.g., T-SQL or ANSI SQL). If you would like us to consider adding a parameterization option, please file a feature request with some use cases at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.